# Evaluating differential equations with degree higher than 1.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would you rationalize the equation $y''+ \sqrt{y'} + xy = 0$ ?
What about for a more abstract case like $y''^{1/m} + y'^{1/n} + C = 0$,
where m,n, and C are positive integers?
How do higher degrees effect the solution of differential equations?

Comment: @W.mu. Did you try with the first case ?

Comment: For $y'>c>0$ you should be able to apply all standard theorems for non-linear ODE. What do you understand under "rationalize"? Where is the "higher degree", all powers are 1 or smaller than 1. It makes not much sense to apply the notion of "degree" to ODE that are not polynomials in the variables and their derivatives.

Comment: @LutzL. By rationalize I mean removing the fractional powers of derivatives. Honestly I am a bit confused about the concept of degree.

Comment: Why would you do that? As it is, the second derivative is uniquely determined by value and first derivative, it is easy to form the first order system. Computing the square in the first equation to eliminate the square root introduces an additional value for $y''$, so it is not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

For $y''+\sqrt{y'}+xy=0$ , you can consider as the ODE of the type http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=429